# ListView displays data only after it is played

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm having a hard time with XAML in Xamarin. Forms: The page is called and displayed without loading the data from the ListView (although the ListView is rendered because it changes the background color in its region).

Then, after I give a touch in the area of the ListView the data is presented i.e. initially the ListView shows nothing and after my touch on the screen it displays the data. However I have no event calling any refresh. I have already made sure of the code that the data is being received by it in a correct manner. Does anyone have any suggestions?

The following is the XAML code:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Coletas.Layouts.DetalheColeta">
    <ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
        <ToolbarItem Name="itemVisualizar" Order="Primary" Icon="pesquisar.png" Text="Visualizar" Priority="0" />
    </ContentPage.ToolbarItems>
    <ListView x:Name="Coleta" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" BackgroundColor="#FFCC80">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ViewCell>
                    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Text="{Binding Coleta, StringFormat='Coleta {0:000000}'}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="12"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Remetente}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding EnderecoRem}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding BairroRem}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CidadeRem}"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding ReferenciaRem}"/>

                        <Label Text="{Binding Destinatario}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="12"/>
                        <Label Text="{Binding CidadeDes}"/>

                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" >
                            <Label Text="{Binding Peso, StringFormat='Peso: {0:0.00}'}"/>
                            <Label Text=" "/>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Quantidade, StringFormat='Volume: {0:0.00}'}"/>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </StackLayout>
                </ViewCell>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</ContentPage>
```

The code that calls the DetalheColeta page is the below. This code is on another separate page:

```
private void GradeColetas_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var item = e.SelectedItem as GridList;

            if (item != null)
            {
                var id = item.Coleta;
                Navigation.PushAsync(new DetalheColeta(id));
                ((ListView)sender).SelectedItem = null;
            };            
        }
```

Any idea?

Comment: ?... You are already displaying a DetalheColeta page and then creating another DetalheColeta instance with the selected item and pushing that to the navigation stack?

Comment: The GradeColetas_ItemSelected code is on another page. This other page calls the DetalheColeta page. I put it there just to have a reference to how I'm calling the page.

Answer (score 1):

Discovered! The problem is in the constructor of the DetalheColeta page when using the Task. There is nothing wrong with the XAML and the previous page call. I executed the program in UWP and the message appeared: "The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread". I was testing in the Xamarin Live Player and did not give error. When correcting the call came to work.

Before:

```
public DetalheColeta (int collection)
        {
            InitializeComponent () 
            Coleta_DetalheAsync (Collection)
        }
```

Now:

```
public DetalheColeta (int collection)
        {
            InitializeComponent ()
            Coleta_DetalheAsync (collection).Wait ();
        }
```

Before:

```
Private async void Coleta_DetalheAsync (int collection)
        {
        Code
        }
```

Now:

```
Private async Task Coleta_DetalheAsync (int collection)
        {
        Code
        }
```

Comment: It's not surprising this was a threading issue. Your solution doesn't look like what I would recommend, however. If loading the data requires some processing or network calls, you don't want to be doing that synchronously (blocking the UI thread), nor do you generally want to do it in the constructor. A better approach would be overriding the OnAppearing method and kicking off an async method there, while showing an activity indicator in the UI, and then marshaling back to the UI thread via Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread.